# Android adb shell ping - This version of ping should NOT run with privileges. Aborting

Tags: android, shell, adb, ping

I am trying to perform a ping via adb shell on a Galaxy S5. I am able to perform this same ping command without issue on a Galaxy S4. Does anyone know how to bypass this? "This version of ping should NOT run with privileges. Aborting"

Ping commands:

```
adb shell
ping www.google.com
```

Comment: is your GS4 on the same version of android as your GS5?

Comment: No, gs5 is 4.4.2, gs4 is 4.3...and now it isn't working on the gs4 anymore. im not sure what i did...this was working the other day.

Comment: why do you need a ping?

Comment: try using the ip address instead of the domain name

Comment: I am using an address actually, but i can't give it out which is why i gave google.com. Sorry, i should i have mentioned that. Also, I am able to perform the ping on my non rooted gs4.

Comment: I am able to ping from a different 4.4 device. Are you sure that the device is on the same network as the ip your are trying to ping? Can you hit the same ip from the browser? Do you get responses if you do `ping 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: if your version of the `ping` binary does not like being run from `root` - then run it from `shell` user `su 2000 ping 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the permission of the ping(a file in /system/bin/) from rwsr-xr-x to rwxr-xr-x, it's done!

Answer (score 1):

If "root", run ping as "net_raw" user:

```
su net_raw
ping www.google.com
```